# How to remove element from two sides of many-to-many self-referencing relation?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have this entity with many to many self-referencing on $friendsWithMe and $myFriends:

```
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Many Users have Many Users.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="myFriends")
     */
    private $friendsWithMe;

    /**
     * Many Users have many Users.
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @JoinTable(name="friends",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $myFriends;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->friendsWithMe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->myFriends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

I have 2 function like this:

```
    /**
     * Remove friendsWithMe
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $friendsWithMe
     */
    public function removeFriendsWithMe(\AppBundle\Entity\User $friendsWithMe)
    {
        $this->friendsWithMe->removeElement($friendsWithMe);
    }


/**
 * Remove myFriends
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $myFriends
 */
public function removeMyFriends(\AppBundle\Entity\User $myFriends)
{
    $this->myFriends->removeElement($myFriends);
}
```

**removeFriensWithMe()** working correctly but **removeMyFriends()** not working in persist.

Comment: What is triggering those methods?

Comment: Doctrine can handle these kind of things with something like  `* @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")`

Comment: @mickdev where use it?

Comment: @mickdev i use it in two joinColumn but not working yet

Comment: Please show how you are using the methods. e.g. `$em->find('app:User', 1)->removeMyFriends($em->getRefernece('app:User', 2)); $em->flush();`

Comment: `$task = $form->getData(); 
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($task);
$em->flush();`
@fyrye

Comment: i have form that work on user entity

Comment: Please show your `FormType` code in your question as it may be related to the issue. Along with your controller code.

Comment: How do you actually use your 2 functions ? Manually, at prePersist, preRemove etc. ? If you call them manually, can you provide the code of your controller as @fyrye suggested ?

Comment: Without seeing the FormType or Controller code, I will suggest adapting https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/3121916 to work with your code. In general ManyToMany relationships are not automatic, forcing you to call the desired methods to maintain the relationship(s) between the associated entities.